# Zephir PHP extension built on Mac M1 doesn't work on the Ubuntu server

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, zephir

I have used the Zephir lang for building the PHP extension. I'm using the Mac M1 and build the extension inside the docker container using Ubuntu 21.10 image with the same PHP verison 8.0. But the output .so extension doesn't work on the Ubuntu server. If I build the extension inside the docker container using Ubuntu 21.10 image on the Window, the extension works. Do you know why and how can I fix that issue?

Comment: At a guess, it's the intel chip vs M1. The M1 architecture is quite a bit different from Intel and AMD, and I know it's caused issues with other software.

Comment: Do you think it impacts even we run in the same Ubuntu container?